# Architectural issue with Generic Repository, Unit Of Work, Unity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, unity-container

I am working on one of my project architecture using MVC5, EntityFramework, Unity, UnitOfWork and Generic Repository also i have not used AutoMapper or anything else similar to AutoMapper.

Whenever I perform update for first time it works perfectly, but for second time onwards it gives me below error.

> Attaching an entity of type 'EntityModel.tblCompanyMaster' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

Error occurs in update method right here [_dbSet.Attach(entity)]

```
 public virtual void UpdateEntity(TEntity entity, string[] NoUpdateProperty = null)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
      .
      .
     }
```

Here are my Code:

1) Unity

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterComponents()
    {
        var container = new UnityContainer();
        //container.RegisterType<DbContext, dbTestCMSEntities>();
        container.RegisterSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();
        container.RegisterSingleton(typeof(IDbHelper<>), typeof(DbHelper<>));            
        container.RegisterSingleton<ICompanyMasterBL, tblCompanyMasterBL>();            
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

2) Unit Of Work

```
    public interface IUnitOfWork
{
    dbTestCMSEntities dbContext { get; }
    void Save();
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork, IDisposable
{
    public dbTestCMSEntities dbContext { get; }
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public UnitOfWork(dbTestCMSEntities context)
    {
        dbContext = context;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                dbContext.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this._disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

3) Generic Repository

```
public interface IDbHelper<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    bool Exists(object pkId);
    TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> order = null);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetMany(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> order = null);
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetPagedList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, Int64>> _order, int currentPageIndex, out int Total);
    void InsertEntity(TEntity entity);
    void InsertEntity(List<TEntity> entity);
    void UpdateEntity(TEntity entity, string[] NoUpdateProperty = null);
    void UpdateEntity(List<TEntity> entity, string[] NoUpdateProperty = null);
    void Delete(object id);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    void DeleteEntity(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition);
}

public class DbHelper<TEntity> : IDbHelper<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    protected readonly dbTestCMSEntities _dbContext;
    protected DbSet<TEntity> _dbSet;
    public DbHelper(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _dbContext = unitOfWork.dbContext;
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public bool Exists(object pkId)
    {
        return _dbSet.Find(pkId) != null;
    }

    public TEntity GetFirst(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> order = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> lstResult = _dbSet.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        if (order != null)
            lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(order).AsQueryable();
        if (condition != null)
            lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().Where(condition).AsQueryable();

        TEntity entity = lstResult.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
        return entity;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetMany(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, string>> order = null)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> lstResult = _dbSet.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        if (condition != null)
            lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().Where(condition).AsQueryable();
        if (order != null)
            lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().OrderBy(order).AsQueryable();
        return lstResult;
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetPagedList(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition, Expression<Func<TEntity, Int64>> _order, int currentPageIndex, out int Total)
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> lstResult = _dbSet.AsNoTracking().AsQueryable();
        if (condition != null)
            lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().Where(condition).AsQueryable();
        Total = lstResult.Count();
        lstResult = lstResult.AsNoTracking().OrderByDescending(_order).AsQueryable().Skip((currentPageIndex - 1) * StringUtility.ItemsPerPage).Take(StringUtility.ItemsPerPage);
        return lstResult;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert single record
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    public virtual void InsertEntity(TEntity entity)
    {
        _dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Insert multiple records
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    public virtual void InsertEntity(List<TEntity> entity)
    {
        _dbSet.AddRange(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update single entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <param name="NoUpdateProperty"></param>
    public virtual void UpdateEntity(TEntity entity, string[] NoUpdateProperty = null)
    {
        _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
        if (NoUpdateProperty != null)
        {
            foreach (string item in NoUpdateProperty)
            {
                _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(entity).Property(item).IsModified = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Update multiple entity
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity"></param>
    /// <param name="NoUpdateProperty"></param>
    public virtual void UpdateEntity(List<TEntity> entity, string[] NoUpdateProperty = null)
    {
        foreach (TEntity item in entity)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(item);
            _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
            if (NoUpdateProperty != null)
            {
                foreach (string item1 in NoUpdateProperty)
                {
                    _dbContext.Entry<TEntity>(item).Property(item1).IsModified = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Delete method for the entities. Delete one record only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="id"></param>
    public virtual void Delete(object id)
    {
        TEntity entityToDelete = _dbSet.Find(id);
        Delete(entityToDelete);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Generic Delete method for the entities. Delete one record only.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entityToDelete"></param>
    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (_dbContext.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            _dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        _dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Delete one or many records based on given condition
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="condition"></param>
    public void DeleteEntity(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> condition)
    {
        _dbSet.RemoveRange(_dbSet.Where(condition));
    }
}
```

I have tried many ways but doesn't help me out, i believe i did something wrong with Unity & Unit Of Work, but hard to identify. Thanks in advance to help me out.

Comment: `throw ex;` is a bad practice. Just don't catch the exception if you're not doing anything with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code helps me to find my solution, just call this method before Attach() while update:

```
public Boolean Exists(T entity) {
var objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this._dbContext).ObjectContext;
var objSet = objContext.CreateObjectSet<T>();
var entityKey = objContext.CreateEntityKey(objSet.EntitySet.Name, entity);

Object foundEntity;
var exists = objContext.TryGetObjectByKey(entityKey, out foundEntity);

if (exists) {
    objContext.Detach(foundEntity);
}
return (exists);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice though. With ORM like entity framework, you better understand how UoW works. Detaching the entity and reattaching it is meaningless. Why don`t you modify your attached entity itself?

Answer (score 0):

> Whenever I perform update for first time it works perfectly, but for second time onwards it gives me below error.

Probably you are attempting to re-use a DbContext instance for multiple requests.  Your DI container appears to be registering things as singletons.  The DbContext should be scoped per-request.

Comment: I have tried adding DbContext scope to per-request but no luck, might possible i did in wrong way, can u pls suggest exact change in UnityConfig which u r talking about.